# How to click the video to change video source in html

Tags: javascript, html, video, onclick

I'm sorry that my english is not very good, I searched for many methods I could find on the Internet, but they were all unsuccessful.

My idea: When the website is opened, a video will be automatically played (A). When the mouse clicks on the video (rather than some buttons), video A will be replaced with video B, and keep the same size and format, and be on the same web page. And when the mouse is clicked again, video B is changed to video A again.

This is the code I tried but it failed：

```js
function setVideo() {

    document.getElementById("video-01").src="demo/2.mp4";

}
```

```html
<div class="video" id="video-one" οnclick="setVideo()">

    <video id="video-01">
        <source src="demo/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>  

</div>
```

I haven't learned how to program, so I don't know how to do it. I have tried to use  in HTML to link to another video, but this will change the style of the page.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const videoA = 'https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/attractive-woman-blogger-speaks-about-professional-voice-over-and-video-id1253606799'
const videoB = 'https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/aerial-shot-flying-along-road-with-driving-vehicles-trucks-and-cars-video-id1251170644'
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const currentVideo = evt.target.getAttribute('src')

  if (currentVideo === videoA) {
    evt.target.setAttribute('src', videoB)
  } else {
    evt.target.setAttribute('src', videoA)
  }
})
```

```html
<video autoplay muted width="480" height="320" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/attractive-woman-blogger-speaks-about-professional-voice-over-and-video-id1253606799"></video>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me! So should I change "document.getElementById("video-01").src="demo/2.mp4";" to "document.querySelector('source').setAttribute('src', 'demo/2.mp4')"? But this doesn’t work. I don’t know why. Clicking on the video can only make it play and pause. : (

Comment: That's another problem. And you need to see all the code for that

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... What should I do to achieve the effect I want?

Comment: Look at it now.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you very much, but I want to know why I can run normally on this page and on Codepen, but when I switch to VS Code, the video doesn’t change when I click on it again?